# Does the following function has a maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, irrational-numbers, maxima-minima

$f$: [$0$,$1$] $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$

if  x rational:  $f$($x$) = $x$

if x irrational: $f$($x$) = $ \frac{1}{x}$

So I think, that this function doesn't have a maximum. 
If I consider the fact that the $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}$ $\frac{1}{x}$ = $\infty$ then of course the function does not have a maximum. But how can I show that this function does not a maximum? So I'm searching for a "clean" proof.

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Hint. Look at the values of $f$ when $x = 1/n\sqrt{2}$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$. You don't need anything about limits.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote ?

Comment: Your reasoning seems okay, but you need what @Peter mentioned to show why the limit approaches infinity.

Comment: Thank you Peter,Remy, Ethan. Of course the irrational numbers are dense in [0,1]. So I can pick $x$ like Ethan Bolker does. x is in [0,1] and f(x) is  n*sqrt(2). and this goes to infinity. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : The set of irrational numbers in the interval $[0,1]$ is dense in $[0,1]$. In other words, there are irrational numbers arbitary close to $0$ and greater than $0$.